# Selectively Mock Services when Testing Angular with Karma

Tags: angularjs, service, mocking, karma-runner, q

While there have been many questions around mocking an individual Angular service in Karma, I am having an issue with making my mocks more ubiquitous throughout testing my application.

In my current setup, I have a module called `serviceMocks` that includes a factory with a mock of each service in the application.

Contrived example:

```
angular.module('serviceMocks',['ngMock'])
    .factory('myServiceOne', function() {...})
    .factory('myServiceTwo', function($httpBackend,$q) {...})
```

This works great when testing controllers and directives which may use one or more services as a dependency. I include my app's module and the serviceMocks module within my testfile, and each service is properly substituted.

```
beforeEach(module('myApp'));
beforeEach(module('serviceMocks'));

it('properly substitutes mocks throughout my tests', function() {...});
```

However, when testing a service itself I cannot include the serviceMocks module, as the service I am testing is substituted by its mock making the tests useless.  However, I would still like *all other* services mocked as a service may depend on one or more services for its execution.

One way I thought of doing this was to make my service mocks globally available, perhaps by attaching an object to `window` that holds the mocks.  I could then include the mocks individually when testing services like so:

```
beforeEach(module('myApp', function($provide) {
    $provide.value('myServiceOne',window.mocks.myServiceOneMock);
    $provide.value('myServiceTwo',window.mocks.myServiceTwoMock);
});
```

However this approach did not work, because some of the mocks use `$q` or other angular services to function properly, and these services are not properly injected when simply attaching the factory object to the window.

I am looking for a way to test services while having a single location to define mocks for all services. Possibilities I imagine but have been unable to succeed with:

- A) Have the `serviceMocks` module's .run() block run before the
  config stage for `myApp`'s module. *(In which case I could attach
  each service to the window as the angular dependencies would be
  properly injected, and inject each as shown above)*
- B) Be able to override the service that I'm testing with its *actual* implementation in the test files of each service
- C) Otherwise be able to define and access these mocks globally, while still ensuring each mock has access to certain angular services such as `$q`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question contains a clue to the answer. If `serviceMocks` module causes design issues, using it is a mistake.

The proper pattern is to have one module per unit (mocked service in this case). `ngMock` is **not** needed, it is loaded automatically in Jasmine tests. The modules can be used one by one:

```
beforeEach(module('app', 'serviceOneMock', 'serviceTwoMock'));
```

Or joined together:

```
angular.module('serviceMocks', ['serviceOneMock', 'serviceTwoMock'])
```

There are not so many cases when `serviceMocks` module should exist at all. Just because a decision which services should be mocked and which should not is made for each `describe` block.

Most times mocked services are individual for current spec or depend on local variables. In this case the services are mocked in-place:

```
var promiseResult;

beforeEach(module('app'));
beforeEach(module({ foo: 'instead of $provide.value(...)' });
beforeEach(($provide) => {
  $provide.factory('bar', ($q) => {
    return $q.resolve(promiseResult);
  }
});
...
```

Doing this in dedicated `serviceOneMock`, etc. modules may require mocked services to be refactored any moment it becomes obvious they are too generic and don't suit the case well.

If mocked service is used more than once in specs with slightly different behaviour and results in WET tests, it is better to make a helper function that will generate it for current spec rather than hard-coding it to `serviceOneMock`, etc. modules.